# Sub-category and category in permalink structure

Tags: permalinks

Is there any way (plugin or function), to include the sub-category and the category automatically in the permalink structure?

I want an URL structure like this:

`category/subcategory/posttitle/`

Answer (score 6):

set the permalink as

```
  /%category%/%postname%/
```

When you set a category parent of child, the permalink will be

```
  ../category/child-category/postitle
```

I tried and worked fine!

Regards

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It's working for me!
But for this you need to assign only "sub-category" to the post.
Means, I have a post under "parent category > sub-category1", so, I will assign "sub-category1" to the post and not the "parent category" and "sub-category1".

Comment: Just to add clarity; **only assign the child-category to include both parent and child in the URL**, otherwise, if you pick both then it will assign it to parent only in the URL