# Most efficient use of custom taxonomies, categories, and pages

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, hierarchical

I've been researching the difference of taxonomies vs. categories vs. custom post types vs. etc. and have been beginning to pickup on the differences. However I still can't wrap my head around when it is the best time to use these elements for my current site.

*Background:*
I am creating a travel-review website where people can review different places around the world. Restaurants, tours, sight seeing, or whatever else people like, can be reviewed.Since there are a ton of places around the world, this site will have a ton of content which makes good permalink structure very important. So far I have only used categories to display my content.

I'm shooting for a permalink structure like this:

```
site.com/destinations/continent/country/city/
```

Continent is a subcategory of destinations, country is a subcategory of continent, and city is a subcategory of country. As of now I'm having trouble **forming a permalink structure with subcategories** since some posts will have extra categories beside the 1 (either cont,country,or city) like restaurants, travel-logs, etc.

Am I doing this right? Should I be using all categories and sub categories or is there a better approach? If this is the right way, how do I get a permalink structure like the one above?

```
/%category%/%postname%
```

is not working for me and only displays the parent category.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to link the subcategory in your permalink only, here you go. Just check the child category only.

[Sub-category and category in permalink structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30350/sub-category-and-category-in-permalink-structure)

Comment: Thanks! But I have a problem when I am using multiple categories (for example: restaurant reviews) that mess up the structure.